# MongoDB get data by comparing an hour of date object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, criteria

I want to get data by comparing an hour of the date object.

```
> db.client.findOne()
  {
        "_id" : NumberLong(1),
        "clientId" : "TESTCLIENT",
        "serverType" : 17,
        "dateCreated" : ISODate("2020-06-10T15:08:02.383Z"),
        "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2020-06-10T15:08:02.383Z")
  }
```

From the client collection, I want to get data between 15:00 to 16:00 of hour (any date) from dateCreated. 
For that I've tried to use following query to get data but unable get results.

```
db.client.find({   
    "dateCreated": {     
        "$gte": 15 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        "$lt": 16 * 60 * 60 * 1000   
    } 
})
```

Please let me know if there is any other way to get results by comparing hours of the date object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation with [$hour](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/index.html#hour-aggregation) for that:

```
db.client.aggregate([
   {$match:
     {$expr:
       {$eq:[ 
            15,
            {$hour: {
                 date: "$dateCreated",
                 timezone: "GMT"
             }}
       ]}
     }
   }
])
```

Comment: The date could be anything. here it will become fix 2020-06-10.

Thanks